# Why passing empty string to Vue component Boolean props considered truthy?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Please see this minimum example, I have a simple component like this

### HelloWorld.vue

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="show">I will show even if show prop is passed as empty string</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      show: Boolean,
    },
  };
</script>
```

Now, If I do this to that component

### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <HelloWorld :show="show" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        show: "",
      };
    },
    components: {
      HelloWorld,
    },
  };
</script>
```

It will render out that string!

Why is this happening?

An empty string is considered falsy but is truthy in the Vue component, that's quite weird.

I probably get why it does this way because now you are enabled to do this

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- you can just write show -->
    <HelloWorld show />
  </div>
</template>
```

However, I think the **template-compiler** should do this thing because take a look at JSX

[image]

It supports the shorthand at compiler level, so I was wondering why Vue design like this.

Comment: Bigger question, why are you typing the variable as a boolean but assigning a string to it?

Comment: It's a common use case, say if you have an input type text element, it's default value might be an empty string, what if I want to render something once user fill out the input, this is one use case.

Comment: That's completely different.  You have a `show` variable here that you are typing as a boolean with the intention of setting it to true if it should show, and false if it should not.  Setting it as a non-boolean doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you are going to store actual string values in the element, and use the length of the string to derive the truthy state of it, then it should be typed as string and not boolean.

Comment: If it's really that not making sense, why Vue did not throw a warning about it?

Comment: Because that's typescript, not vue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vuejs use Boolean props as in HTML, where empty string will be considered as true

[They wrote it in their documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Built-In-Directives)